# Implement a pipe in C

Tags: c, shell, fork, pipe, wait

I try to implement a pipe in C but I have a little problem:

Here is my function :

```
void commandeTube(char * c1, char * c2) {
    int c1toc2[2];
    int c2toPere[2];
    pid_t pidc1, pidc2;
    if(pipe(c1toc2) && pipe(c2toPere)) {
        perror("Erreur");
        errno=0;
        return ;
    }
    pidc2 = fork();
    if(pidc2 != 0) {
        pidc1=fork();
        if(pidc1!=0) {

            int status;
            waitpid(pidc1,&status,0);
            char buffer[1024]={0};
            int n;
            while((n=read(c2toPere[0],buffer,1024))==1024)
                write(1,buffer,n);
            write(1,buffer,n);


        }
        else if(pidc1==0){
            write(STDOUT_FILENO,"C1\n",3);
            /*On est dans C1*/
            close(c1toc2[0]);
            dup2(c1toc2[1],1);
            char * argc1[10];
            constructTab(c1,argc1);
            write(STDOUT_FILENO,"C1 exe\n",7);
            if(execvp(argc1[0],argc1)==-1) {
                perror("Erreur execlp");
                errno=0;
                return;
            }
            freeTab(argc1);
            write(STDOUT_FILENO,"C1 fin\n",7);
        } 

    }
    else {
            /*C2*/
            write(STDOUT_FILENO,"C2\n",3);
            int stat;
            char * argc2[10];
            constructTab(c2,argc2);
            close(c1toc2[1]);
            /*close(c2toPere[0]);*/
            dup2(c1toc2[0],STDIN_FILENO);
            /*dup2(c2toPere[1],1);*/
            write(STDOUT_FILENO,"C2 exe\n",7);
            if(execvp(argc2[0],argc2)==-1) {
                perror("Erreur execlp");
                errno=0;
                return;
            }
            freeTab(argc2);
            write(STDOUT_FILENO,"C2 fin\n",7);

    }
}
```

For example, if I have this :

> > cmd1 | cmd2

The main process creates 2 children, one for `cmd1` and another for `cmd2`. The output of `cmd1` is redirected to the input of `cmd2`. My problem is that `cmd2` is executed before `cmd1`, so if I type:

> > ls | wc

for example, wc will be launched first. That's what I see in my shell:

```
C2
C1
C2 exe
```

How to fully execute C1 before execute C2? Earlier, I tried to make c1 child of c2 with `waitpid(c1,...,..);` but I had the same result.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to redirect the output of the first command into the input of the second command you might consider reading `man 2 pipe`, there is a great  example there which should put you on right track.

http://linux.die.net/man/2/pipe

Answer (score 0):

Your code works for me but the C1 exe message was being redirected to the pipe.  I changed all the `STDOUT_FILENO` to `STDERR_FILENO`, then I saw

```
C2
C1
C1 exe
C2 exe
    193     194    1502
```

when running with ls wc.